# How to Read Excel file in a web-worker in a VueJS Project

Tags: excel, vue.js, asynchronous, web-worker

Currently i have a Excel file having **150,000+** rows and multiple sheets, and i am using **read-excel-file** library to read files **synchronous** by which the browser stuck! so i want to push that load on a different thread so the main thread can render UI flawlessly and thats why i want to use Web-Worker for that and currently i am in a **VueJs** project and i find a library **vue-worker** for the web worker but got this error and cant find any solution.

> Error: Failed to execute 'postMessage' on 'Worker': function readXlsxFile(file) { ...

*Here is a mini example of it:*
URL: https://codesandbox.io/embed/vue-template-u8swi?fontsize=14

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <input type="file" @change="onFIleChange">
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import readXlsxFile from "read-excel-file";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {},
  data: () => {
    return {
      file: null,
      rows: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    onFIleChange(e) {
      this.file = e.target.files[0];

      this.$worker
        .run(
          (file, readXlsxFile) => {
            return readXlsxFile(file);
          },
          [this.file, readXlsxFile]
        )
        .then(rows => {
          this.rows = rows;
          console.log(this.rows);
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.error(e);
        });
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```